# Is it possible to use nicematrix with longtable?

Tags: longtable, nicematrix

I really like `nicematrix` as a package because I think it is very intuitive and has the best consistent colouring, which does not have the problem of showing a small white cell separator when viewing in some PDF viewers.

That's why I wanted to know if it is possible to combine `nicematrix` with `longtable`?

If it is not possible, are there any plans for making it possible to use the colouring of `nicematrix` in a `longtable`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I'm the author of `nicematrix`). At this time, there is no way to have breakable tables with `nicematrix`. Sorry...

Maybe it will be possible in a future version but it's difficult because of the PGF/Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix`. The PGF/Tikz nodes of both parts of the tabular should be created on the right page...