# Can I create NiceTabular table with length more then 1 page (as longtable)

Tags: longtable

I need the table in this format , I used other tables as NiceTabular, so I want the same look.
The regular tables which I tried for short tables have some issue with lines in joined cells.

[image]

Comment: Not possible I think. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618357/219947

Comment: You might also consider an alternative approach with `longtblr` of [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray).

Comment: Please, provide as a MWE.

Comment: Which (longtblr of tabularray) prefered with using colored table , \makecell and multirow ?

Comment: @ikif tabularray has its own mechanism for changing cell colours. If you would add a small, but compilable test document to your question, I'm sure you would get answers showing you how to use a longtblr

Comment: @scd what is MWE ?